# primefaces NoClassDefFoundError:SelectEvent error

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

Okay, new primefaces error (for me, anyway). On startup I get:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/primefaces/event/SelectEvent
```

I'm using primefaces 3.3.1 and just verified that there are no conflicts with older primefaces versions. Any ideas? Below is the .xhtml that is causing the error.

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3c.org/1999/xhtml"
xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui" >    

<h:head>

</h:head>
<h:body>
<center>
<h:form id="form">

<p:dataTable id="personTable" var="client" value="#{tableBean.persons}" paginator="true" rows="5"
             selection="#{tableBean.person}" selectionMode="single">

    <p:ajax event="rowSelect" listener="#{tableBean.onUserSelect}" update=":form:displayf" oncomplete="carDialog.show()" />  

    <p:ajax event="rowUnselect" listener="#{tableBean.onUserUnselect}" update=":form:displayf" />

    <f:facet name="header">
        Click "View" button after selecting a row to see details
    </f:facet>

    <p:column headerText="Name">
        #{client.name}
    </p:column>

    <p:column headerText="Address">
        #{client.address}
    </p:column>

    <p:column headerText="Phone" >
        #{client.phone}
    </p:column>

</p:dataTable>

<p:dialog id="dialog" header="Person Detail" widgetVar="personDialog" resizable="false"  
            showEffect="explode" hideEffect="explode">  

    <h:panelGrid id="displayf" columns="2" cellpadding="4">


        <h:outputText value="Name:" />
        <h:outputText value="#{tableBean.person.name}" />

        <h:outputText value="Address:" />
        <h:outputText value="#{tableBean.person.address}" />

        <h:outputText value="Phone:" />
        <h:outputText value="#{tableBean.person.phone}" />

    </h:panelGrid>
</p:dialog>

</h:form>

</center>
</h:body>
</html>
```

Comment: I don't think there could be any reason other than your classpath issues.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, answer apparently found. When dealing with primefaces:

1. Do not test with IE9/8 (or at least not exclusively). I found some code simply did not work with microsoft but functioned perfectly with Firefox.
2. make sure you are using compatible versions of primefaces and jsf. I'm using primefaces 3.3.1 and mojarra 2.1.1., but be wary of mixing and matching.
3. Also, primefaces is apparently not fully backwardly compatible. Some of the older tutorials may not work with newer versions of primefaces. I noticed that the current user manual / showcase application did not fully work with the older 2.2 primefaces release.
4. Be careful with primefaces, it has some good stuff but it is buggy and the differences between the releases can lead to all kinds of problems.